# why i am getting Tag lost exception on AES authentication in mifare plus and MifareDesfire EV1

Tags: nfc, mifare

I am sending AES authentication command on MifareDesfire tag and getting Tag Lost exception.

As first command code in desfire is : 0xAA with card key num 0x00(master card key)

have tried this on Native authentication (DES) and is working fine for native the command is : (0x0A,0x00)

```
  Sample code 
     :
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                    || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                    || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "discovered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Falied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            byte[] tagResponse = null;

            desfire = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            isodep = IsoDep.get(desfire);

            try {
                isodep.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            byte[] test = new byte[] { (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0x00 };

            try {

                tagResponse = isodep.transceive(test);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            try {
                isodep.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: RF antina problem, i kept tag strongly  in the proximity
AES authentication needs more power to exchange data between PCD and PICC.